# QML: Canvas like a view

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, model-view

I have a set of rectangles provided by c++ backend, and I'd like to paint
each of them on qml side with some extra decorations, colors opacity etc (respecting rectangles' positions and sizes).

I was hoping for some special kind of view which would accept a model containing all these rectangles and then would use them in delegates to define items' positions and sizes.

The best I was able to find is 'Canvas' which I may use to fulfill my needs, but maybe there is something more suitable?

Comment: Does a `Repeater` do what you want?

Comment: @JarMan indeed it does. What a surprise for me:)

Comment: Great, then I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Repeater` can accept a model and instantiate your Rectangles at any size/position.

```
Repeater {
    model: rectangleModel    // Comes from C++

    delegate: Rectangle {
        x: model.x
        y: model.y
        width: model.width
        height: model.height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using listview delegate.

May be you can use QObjectList-based Model, as said in below link

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

In your c++ code expose the required data from rectangles using `Q_PROPERTY`

Comment: I tried @JarMan 's solution which is quite simple and does what I need so I'll go for it.